# Is Burj Khalifa paying itself off?

Tags: economics, dubai

[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Burj_Khalifa&oldid=1068387522):

> The concept of profitability derived from building high density developments and malls around the landmark has proven successful. Its surrounding malls, hotels and condominiums in Downtown Dubai have generated the most revenue from the project as a whole, while the Burj Khalifa itself made little or no profit.

Following the above, I want to ask if as a whole the Burj Khalifa is in a genuine process of paying itself off due to the surrounding revenue now or in the near future?

Comment: If you wish to challenge the claim made on the Wiki page (or request a better source), the Wiki's talk page may be a better place to start.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that

Comment: Burj Khalifa is not a 
standalone construction. The purpose was not to solely build    the tallest building in the world.Burj Khalifa was just the 

 first phase of  $20bn urban  project called  Kingdom City. It is both the economic drive force plus a symbol
Of development status to attract investments.So it's purpose itself was to promote surrounding bussiness in part.

Comment: My question if it has been succesful in that regard and if have evidence to believe that such a construction would actually improve tourism

Comment: Burj Khalifa has an observation deck, as do many tall buildings. Are you suggesting that this one draws no tourists? Why should a claim that it does, and that visitors also dine and go shopping, be skeptical? Or that it needs services industries and accomodation nearby.

Comment: It is intuitive to believe so, but I am asking if there were such similar surveys of such buildings and see if the increase in tourism truly due to the building itself @WeatherVane. I never said they draw 'no tourists' whatsoever

Comment: It is hard to see what your skeptical claim is. Is it that Burj Khalifa made little or no profit, that the surrounding area did, or that the two are unrelated? What is the actual claim that you are disputing?

Comment: There's probably not much good research availible, however you might consider looking at the research on sports stadiums.  there's a lot of work there due to the fact that stadiums often get taxpayers funding and other perks under the assumption that they bring people to the surrounding area who wouldn't otherwise have been there.  It's not perfect comparison though, since often games are long and at night and people drive in and drive out, whereas tall buildings seem to get people who are interested in "making a day of it" when they see them and often stay in the general area longer.

Comment: Good idea:) @eds

Comment: Wikipedia itself is not a great source for a claim, because it is user edited, but what's there _should_ be backed by citations. In this instance, there are two on that paragraph, [numbers 8 and 9 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Burj_Khalifa&oldid=1068387522#cite_note-constructionweekaugust13kingdombeckons-8), both from 2011. The first is a public web page, so you can click through and see if it answers, or provides a better source for, your question. Regarding the mention of Talk Pages for requesting improvements to Wikipedia, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Talk_pages